# bug in LimSolve?

Tags: optimization, xdebug, mathematical-optimization

I believe I had found a bug in the package LimSolve. When running the code below, the procedure causes my R application (64-bit Windows; R version 2.13.1 (2011-07-08)) to crash without warnings or errors. The code to reproduce the error is below:

The 130 kb .rda file required is [here](http://www.sendspace.com/file/vrnv3m):

```
load( "limSolveTest.rda" )

library( lpSolve )

optimResultlpSolve = lp( direction = "min" , 
                         objective.in = g_ ,
                         const.mat = Aeq_ ,
                         const.dir = rep( "=" , nrow( Aeq_ ) ) ,
                         const.rhs = beq_ ,
                         transpose.constraints = FALSE
                         ) # Function should raise an error

# Passes if transpose.constraints = TRUE
```